# Habtm get all unique permissions from more than one role

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have an association HABTM ROLES > PERMISSIONS, and I want to get all permissions from more than one role.

Example:

`Role.find(1,2).permissions.uniq`

In my project, I have a user with 2 roles, and these roles have specific permissions, sometimes equal.

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Do you have a code example of what you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Role.find([1, 2]).map(&:permissions).uniq`